# what should be structure of payload to Import multiple variables to Airflow UI using Curl command?

Tags: python, json, shell, curl, airflow

I am trying to import multiple variables to Airflow UI using Curl command. Getting issue while I am trying to import multiple variable using payload.

I am trying to import multiple variables to Airflow UI using Curl command.
for single variable the following command works fine.

`curl -X 'POST' 'http://10.135.7.13:9081/api/v1/variables' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"key": "string","value": "string"}' --user 'usr:pwd'`

But for multiple variable tried all the possible ways and getting different errors.

**1.**
`curl -X 'POST' 'http://10.135.7.13:9080/api/v1/variables' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}' --user 'usr:pwd'`

```
{
  "detail": "{'value': ['Missing data for required field.'], 'key': ['Missing data for required field.'], 'key2': ['Unknown field.'], 'key1': ['Unknown field.']}",
  "status": 400,
  "title": "Invalid Variable schema",
  "type": "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.2/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/BadRequest"
```

**2.**
`curl -X 'POST' 'http://10.135.7.13:9080/api/v1/variables' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"variables":[{"key": "string","value": "string"},{"key": "string1","value": "string1"}]}' --user 'usr:pwd'`

```
{
  "detail": "{'value': ['Missing data for required field.'], 'key': ['Missing data for required field.'], 'variables': ['Unknown field.']}",
  "status": 400,
  "title": "Invalid Variable schema",
  "type": "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.2/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/BadRequest"
```

**3.**
`curl -X 'POST' 'http://10.135.7.13:9080/api/v1/variables' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '[{"key": "string","value": "string"},{"key": "string1","value": "string1"}]' --user 'usr:pwd'`

```
  "detail": "[{'key': 'string', 'value': 'string'}, {'key': 'string1', 'value': 'string1'}] is not of type 'object'",
  "status": 400,
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "type": "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.2/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/BadRequest"
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand what should be the structure of payload here.

Answer (score 0):

Importing one variable at a time is the only possible way to do so according to the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_variables) and the [code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/971e3226dc3ca43900f0b79c42afffb14c59d691/airflow/models/variable.py#L155).

A workaround can be a for loop over your array:

```
AIRFLOW_URL="http://localhost:8080/api/v1/variables"
AIRFLOW_USERNAME="airflow"
AIRFLOW_PASSWORD="airflow"

# Define the JSON array of variables
VARIABLES='[
    {"key": "var1", "value": "valueA"},
    {"key": "var2", "value": "valueB"},
    {"key": "var3", "value": "valueC"}
]'

# Loop through the JSON array and create each variable using the Airflow REST API
for variable in $(echo "${VARIABLES}" | jq -c '.[]'); do
    key=$(echo "${variable}" | jq -r '.key')
    value=$(echo "${variable}" | jq -r '.value')

    curl -X POST "${AIRFLOW_URL}" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --user "${AIRFLOW_USERNAME}:${AIRFLOW_PASSWORD}" \
        -d "{\"key\": \"${key}\", \"value\": \"${value}\"}"
done
```